# Expanding reference range of formulas which operate on a "database" when more items (rows, columns) are added to the database (tricks?, no VBA)

Tags: excel

I included possible solutions to this problem below, however I'm hoping that perhaps somebody knows other ways and/or some neat tricks to achieve this.

**1)** Say we have a simple "database" in excel (as in the screenshot below).

**2)** Say we have formulas which operate on this entire range, like for example the VLOOKUP function in the screenshot.

**3)** *Now obviously, if we added more rows to this "database" the existing VLOOKUP function will NOT include them - it will still operate only on the previously declared range.*

[image]

**Possible solutions:**

1) One could obviously solve this problem with a VBA macro, however I would like to consider solving this with just the Excel formulas/features

2) One could use the range for the entire sheet in the original VLOOKUP i.e. $B$2:**$D$1048576** and include a function not to take blank cells into consideration

**Do you know any other solutions or neat tricks?**

Thank you in Advance!

Danny

Comment: You can use offset () and count () formulas to generate a dynamic range. Otherwise Excel tables achieve a similar outcome

Comment: That's partially true, as I would have to change the offset as more rows/columns are added into the database...right? Then I could just as well change the range. I'm guessing there are no other ways, but then again that's why I posted this - maybe somebody will surprise me

Comment: The best solution is a Table and Structured References,  but you could simply refer to the whole column, `B:D`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your range to table and refer to table ranges in formula.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest switching to `Index`/`Match` or `XLookup` to avoid the magic number for column offset

Comment: Thank you Chris Neilsen, I usually use 'Index with Match' I used Vlookup to make the example look simpler!

Comment: I haven't thought of using tables, it may be "it". Thank you @basic !